# Ошибка при запуске mpi программы

Tags: c++, mpi

Есть код для параллельного умножения матрицы на вектор:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <mpi.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    int procs_rank, procs_count;
    int i, j, n, local_n;
    double* local_matrix, * vect, * local_result, * matrix, * result;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs_count);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs_rank);
    printf("Введите количество элементов n:");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    local_n = n / procs_count;
    local_matrix = (double*)malloc((local_n * n) * sizeof(double));
    vect = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    local_result = (double*)malloc(local_n * sizeof(double));
    result = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    matrix = (double*)malloc((n * n) * sizeof(double));
    // Инициализируем матрицу в нулевом процессе и рассылаем его части по процессам 
    if (procs_rank == 0)
    {
        //матрицу удобнее рассматривать как одномерный массив но с индексами i*n+j 
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                matrix[i * n + j] = rand();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            vect[i] = rand();
    }
    auto time = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Bcast(vect, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Рассылаем вектор vect 
    MPI_Scatter(matrix, n * local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, local_matrix, n * local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Разделяем матрицу на горизонтальные полосы шириной local_matrix и отпраляем процессам 

    for (i = 0; i < local_n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            local_result[i] += local_matrix[i * n + j] * vect[j];

    MPI_Gather(local_result, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, result, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Собираем результат в нулевом процессе 
    time = MPI_Wtime() - time;
    if (procs_rank == 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%f3.3 \n", result[i]);
        printf("На умножение матрицы (%dx%d) на вектор (%d) потребовалось %lf секунд\n", n, n, n, time);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

В wmpiexec выбираю запускаемый файл, прописываю параметр -localonly и запускаю. Ничего не происходит, нажимаю break и вылезает такая ошибка:

> op_read error on parent context: generic socket failure, error stack:
> MPIDU_Sock_wait(2603): Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно. (errno 64)
> unable to read the cmd header on the parent context, generic socket failure, error stack:
> MPIDU_Sock_wait(2603): Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно. (errno 64).
> connection to my parent broken, aborting.
> state machine failed.
> closesocket failed, sock 1220, error 10093

В исключение брандмауэра добавлял, сам брандмауэр выключал и всё равно не работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, ошибка была в этих строках:

```
printf("Введите количество элементов n:");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
```

Решил указанием значения n при инициализации

```
int i, j, n, local_n;
```